# Nesting formula Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to nest a formula with VBA and place the nested formula in the next cell next to it using an Offset but it does not seem to work correctly. I have tried using a MsgBox to debug and it shows exactly what I want. In the example ActiveCell has a simple SUM.

What I want is to have "=Cell("address",SUM(Sheet1!D3:D4))" in the cell exactly below the Activcell but I keep getting a Run time error 1004. This may be pretty basic but I cannot figure why it is happening.

Thanks for the help :)

```
Sub nestFormula()

Dim form As String

form = "=Cell(""address""," & Replace(ActiveCell.formula, "=", "") & ")"

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = form

MsgBox form

End Sub
```

Comment: the CELL formula in Excel won't accept a SUM formula, please explain what you're trying to achieve with your expected formula

Comment: Im trying to nest the SUM formula with a CELL formula.

Comment: the CELL formula cannot accept a nested SUM. For example your formula =Cell("address",SUM(Sheet1!D3:D4)) is an invalid formula.

Comment: Ohh i see.Thanks. Great insight. Is there a way around this ? 
I would like to get an adjacent cell with =Cell("address",SUM(Sheet1!D3:D4)).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, hence why I asked what you're trying to achieve with your formula :)

Comment: I will change my example. It seems that using the SUM function does not work. Imagine we have an Index formula instead.

I have a range of cells all of them with an Index formula say : "=Index(A1:A4,2,2)" and I want to convert every single Index to its reference.

    Sub nestFormula()

    Dim form As String

    For Each cell In Selection
        form = "=Cell(""address""," & Replace(ActiveCell.formula, "=", "") & 
    ")"
        cell.formula = form
    Next cell

    End Sub

I can't seem to edit the code to become readable in this type of answer :( hope you can understand

Comment: Answered! Thanks! It was all about the Sum formula not working inside of CELL. It worked perfectly with Index